# How to update child list with another object in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to update a child list from a parent adding records to it or updating one of its attributes. I receive the updated model from the Controller but when I try to replace the actual list with the new and save the changes to DB I get the error:

> The instance of entity type 'WorkflowReferenciaExecucoes' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ReferenciaExecucoesId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

I don't have access to the `dbContext` directly because we are using the repository pattern. What I have tried to update the child in the service is:

```
private void Update(Workflow entity)
{
    // entity is my updated model received by controller

    // Getting the actual parent in the database
    var workflow = GetById(entity.WorkflowId);
    workflow.NomeWorkflow = entity.NomeWorkflow;
    workflow.DescricaoWorkflow = entity.DescricaoWorkflow;
    workflow.FgAtivo = entity.FgAtivo;

    // Updating child list
    workflow.WorkflowReferenciaExecucoes = entity.WorkflowReferenciaExecucoes;

    // Trying to save the update gives error
    _uow.WorkflowRepository.Update(entity);
}
```

My parent class is:

```
public class Workflow
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int WorkflowId { get; set; }
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    public int WorkflowTipoId { get; set; }
    public string NomeWorkflow { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoWorkflow { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInclusao { get; set; }
    public bool FgAtivo { get; set; }
    public Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
    public WorkflowTipo WorkflowTipo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<WorkflowReferenciaExecucao> WorkflowReferenciaExecucoes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<WorkflowCondicaoExecucao> WorkflowCondicaoExecucoes { get; set; }
}
```

And child class:

```
public class WorkflowReferenciaExecucao
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ReferenciaExecucaoId { get; set; }
    public int WorkflowId { get; set; }
    public int? ExecucaoWorkflowId { get; set; }
    public int ValorReferenciaExecucao { get; set; }
    public bool FgProcessar { get; set; }
    public bool FgAtivo { get; set; }
}
```

What do I have to do to update the actual list to the new one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the passed in `entity` has duplicates in the `WorkflowReferenciaExecucoes` property - meaning the same `WorkflowReferenciaExecucao` exists twice in that IEnumerable?

Comment: Yeah, I double checked and the updated entity had records with duplicate ReferenciaExecucaoId in WorkflowReferenciaExecucoes, my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can not  update like that you have wrong relationship you class should be like that

```
public class WorkflowReferenciaExecucao
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ReferenciaExecucaoId { get; set; }
    public Workflow Workflow { get; set; }
    public int? ExecucaoWorkflowId { get; set; }
    public int ValorReferenciaExecucao { get; set; }
    public bool FgProcessar { get; set; }
    public bool Fugitive { get; set; }
}
```

```
WorkflowReferenciaExecucao is one and it has only one workflow so when you update Workflow then you have to update only workflow id in WorkflowReferenciaExecucao  don't pass whole object just pass id to change it one to many relationship so on one side you update anything it don't relate to many relationship because it only point to id that it
```

Comment: But I need to edit FgAtivo in some records of WorkflowReferenciaExecucao and adding other records of WorkflowReferenciaExecucao to Workflow

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem when there are multiple child records with the same `ReferenciaExecucoesId` in the update entity.

You can check if this is the case.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I double checked and it really had duplicates with same ReferenciaExecucaoId, my mistake. Thank you!